# give names to start_urls in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am crawling urls from a csv file, and each url has a name. How can I download these urls and save them with their names?

```
reader = csv.reader(open("source1.csv"))
for Name,Sources1 in reader:
    urls.append(Sources1)

class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = urls[1:]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = **Name** + '.pdf' //how can I get the names I read from the csv file?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want to override the [start_requests()](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) method instead of using start_urls?

Example:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    def start_requests(self):
        data = read_csv()
        for d in data:
            yield scrapy.Request(d.url, meta={'name': d.name})
```

The `meta` dict for request will be repassed to the response, so you can later do:

```
def parse(self, response):
    name = response.meta.get('name')
    ...
```